# React/TS/material-ui Using variable as value of grid property throws errors: "No overload matches" and "Type 'number' is not assignable to type..."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, material-ui

**tl;dr:** material-ui throws TS error when using a variable as the value of a grid `xs` property in JSX

---

I'm implementing grids in material-ui with React/TypeScript

I want the width of a particular element to be dependent on how many of that element there are.

It's a simple calculation that outputs a whole number between 12 and 4:

```
const sheets = [0, 1, 2];
const sheetColWidth = sheets.length > 3 ? 3 : 12 / sheets.length;
```

but when I use sheetColWidth (value `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`, of type `number`) as the value for the grid's `xs` property, TS throws an error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & Partial<Record<Breakpoint, boolean | 1 | 6 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 10 | "auto" | 2 | 4 | 8 | 9 | 11 | 12>> & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean | 1 | 6 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 10 | "auto" | 2 | 4 | 8 | 9 | 11 | 12 | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<GridTypeMap<{}, "div">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean | 1 | 6 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 10 | "auto" | 2 | 4 | 8 | 9 | 11 | 12 | undefined'.  TS2769
```

I have a reduced example on Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-dust-cli52

(This has no styles attached as they aren't relevant)

When you load up this, it seems to render fine, but after a moment, the `xs` property on L.18 gets a red error underline and hovering over it reveals the error.

In my application, the app just crashes with the TS error.

Replace the `sheetColWidth` on L.18 with a permitted number, the error goes away and everything is fine.

Bit confused as the value of the variable is one of the enumerated permitted values in the Grid interface.

I tried string interpolation for the hell of it, but then it's rejected for being a string, as it should be:

```
xs={`${sheetColWidth}`}
```

I tried casting the value to a string and back to a number - this changed nothing, and quite right:

```
const sheetColWidth = parseInt(sheets.length > 3 ? 3 : 12 / sheets.length + '');
```

I'm stumped.

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `sheetColWidth` when you get the error?

Comment: Thanks for the question @Remolten.

The values are 1, 2, 3 or 4, as numbers, not strings - this is confirmed both by the error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type [...]` and by logging `typeof sheetColWidth`

Will update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran into this same problem. My solution was to define a type consistent with the acceptable width values.

```
type GRID_SIZES = 'auto'|true|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12;

const GridDisplay = () => {
  let width: GRID_SIZES = 12;
  if (horizontal) {
    width = 6;
  }
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={width}>
        Grid Item
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me - the task got parked for other priorities for ages, and by the time I came back to it I solved it much the same way, but had forgotten about thee SO post. Sloppy of me.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the types available in the library itself:

```
import { Grid, GridSize } from "@material-ui/core";
// ...
const sheetColWidth: Gridsize = 1;
```

Comment: You are missing a comma in the import statement imho